# Checkbox count in error JSP

Tags: jsp, checkbox

I have an error when it comes to checkbox count. I have a checkbox appear next to my data. For example, I ticked 2 checkboxes, and I press delete. It will always appear my count as 0. How do I fix this error ? I have tried several ways to fix this but my count will always display as 0.

[This is a picture of the message display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFlMX.png)

```
 String[] id = request.getParameterValues("deletechkbox");
        int count=0;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Step 2: Define Connection URL
            String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medicloud?user=root&password=root";
            // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

            if (id != null)
            {

        for(int i=0; i<id.length; i++){

        String sqlStr = "DELETE from exercise1 where id=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id[i]));
        int rec = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rec==1)
            count++;
        }
        }
```

This is my checkbox setup.

```
<td style="width: 5%"><input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox"
value="<%=id%>" form="multipleDele" name="deletechkbox" /></td>
```

This is my form for the checkboxes

```
<form action="delete.jsp" id="multipleDele" method="post">
<strong>Selected Exercise(s) to: </strong><input type="submit"
value="Delete" id="mulDelBtn" name="deleteMultipleBtn" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is this in a `<form>` or did you build the query ? Did you checked the `String[] id = request.getParameterValues("deletechkbox");` result ? Also, you don't need to create a new `PreparedStatement` for each value, just need to set the value and execute.

Comment: It's in a form. How do I check the result of that string ? I am really new into coding. Can you guide me through along ? @AxelH

Comment: form action should be in the form tag, not in your input tag. Also, learn jstl and expression language. It will make your life easier. You are using a scriplet to output the value of the id. With EL, all you would have to do is ${id}.

Comment: But this is a project given to me by the lecturer. They want me to create this within a month or so. And plus this is all brand new to me. So I really need someone to help me with this and I can hand in my project asap

Comment: Please show us the `<form` you have by [edit]ing the question

Comment: @AxelH Is this the piece of information you need ? (I edited my post)

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: Your Input checkbox is not in the form so the request will not hold any `deletechbox` value.

Comment: @AxelH So I copy + paste my input inside my form ?

Comment: @raviraja does my js code plays a part in the error as well ? o.o

Comment: if you want to delete multiple records at atime, JS is needed.

Comment: @raviraja ohhh How do I do that ? Teach me